# Drupal 7 overriding node.tpl.php

Tags: drupal-7, overriding, nodes

I am trying to override the front page node, however after following the guide from the official site, it's not working.

Guide: https://www.drupal.org/node/1585528

I have taken `node.tpl.php` and renamed it to `node--front.tpl.php` and made changes to the layout, saved and cleared cache. The changes are not being displayed.

Now if I edit node.tpl.php directly it shows the changes, anyone know what I am doing wrong to override specific node templates?

**EDIT:**
I want to move the title below the image being displayed in the front page.

See below: Moving the title block under the content block, moves the title down as I want it to do, however how do I specify this for just the front page and not all nodes? (renaming `node.tpl.php` to `node--front.tpl.php` does not work as mentioned above)

In node.tpl.php: (title block)

```
<?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php if (!$page): ?>
  <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>>
    <a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a>
  </h2>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
```

(content block)

```
<div class="content clearfix"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>>
<?php
  // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
  hide($content['comments']);
  hide($content['links']);
  print render($content);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To override the node template for particular node, you need to override the default node.tpl.php. For this copy the existing node.tpl.php file to node--{node_id}.tpl.php.

If you want to override the page template only for front page then you can create page--front.tpl.php file and copy the page.tpl.php file and then modify it as per your requirement.

Still you have issues, then use hook_preprocess_page() in template.php and use dpm() function to find the theme_suggestions that will give the sequence of execution of templates file.

Comment: For your first step, I have copied the node.tpl.php from the main theme folder to my subtheme and renamed it node--front.tpl.php. (What is the node_id for the default front page?) This, does nothing, the changes made in node--front.tpl.php does not display.

Answer (score 0):

you can use node-{nodeid}.tpl.php

It may help you.

Source: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39710/how-do-i-define-a-template-file-for-a-specific-node-id

Thanks
Samit K

samitkhulve.com

Comment: I've tried renaming it—node.tpl.php (in my theme) - copied to my subtheme as node--front.tpl.php. The changes I make in node--front.tpl.php does not display. So there is something missing in the overriding process, unless this is not the right way to do it for the front page.